# Open a specific set of URLs in IE depending on the day of the week

Tags: windows-10, powershell, internet-explorer

How can I create a script that will:

1. open www.google.com, or
2. if www.google.com is open, open www.yahoo.com in a new tab [[ref](https://superuser.com/a/877249/220023)], or
3. if the day is Sunday, open www.bing.com [[ref](https://superuser.com/a/751691/220023)],

in each case using IE on a Windows 10 machine where Edge is the default browser?

Comment: You have everything in your references. Why do not just glue it together or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I have found the pieces of the puzzle; I just do not know how to put them together to achieve the solution I am looking for.

Comment: I've given you one more piece of the puzzle in your other question.

Comment: Thank you. For #2 I am not sure how to check whether www.google.com is open. For #3, I assume I need something like:  `if (get-date).DayOfWeek = "Sunday" {
    $sitesToOpen = "http://bing.com"
} else {
    $sitesToOpen = "http://google.com"
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are not clearly defined, but as far as I understand your problem I can give you this solution: If it is not Sunday, we search all IE instances if the are on google.com, if yes open yahoo.com.

This is not perfect, because if run the script again, you get more yahoo.com tabs (but that case is not specified by you.) and there are other things, plus you should add more checks.

But anyways, here's my approach:

```
# Set BrowserNavConstants to open URL in new tab    
$navOpenInBackgroundTab = 0x1000; # Full list of BrowserNavConstants: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360.aspx

$ie = $null
if (Get-Process iexplore -ea silentlycontinue | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne ""}) {
    #Write-Output "IE is running"
    $ie = (New-Object -COM "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? { $_.Name -eq "Internet Explorer" }
} else {
    $ie = New-Object -COM "InternetExplorer.Application"
    sleep -milliseconds 50
    $ie.visible=$true
}

$today = (get-date).DayOfWeek
# Depending on the day of the week discovered, assign the right day's array into the sitesToOpen array.
switch ($today) { 
    "Sunday" {
        $ie.navigate("http://bing.com"); break
    }
    default {
        $google = $false
        foreach($tab in $ie) {
            if($tab.LocationURL.Contains("www.google.com"))
            {$google = $true; break}
        }
        if($google) {
            $ie.Navigate2("http://yahoo.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);
        } else {
            $ie.navigate("http://google.com")
        }
        break
    }
}
# Cleanup
'ie' | ForEach-Object {Remove-Variable $_ -Force}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to behave exactly as I intended; and I do not get more yahoo.com tabs when I run the script again. (I also found a [solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f7d6f44d-86ee-4988-a55f-1b5345b6472e/how-do-you-maximize-an-internet-explorer-window-via-a-powershell-script) to maximise the window.)

Comment: Great. Btw, why do you want to have this behavior? It's feels a bit weird.

Comment: There are a couple of sites that I use daily, and a different (related) one on Sundays.  Also, I tried adding another site before www.google.com, changing the existing line to `$ie.Navigate2("http://google.com", $navOpenInBackgroundTab);`, but I cannot get www.yahoo.com to open; any ideas?

Comment: Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service.